# How to generate corporate level test data for Active Directory

Tags: testing, active-directory, unboundid-ldap-sdk

Background: I'm working on developing client functionality for OpenLDAP and ActiveDirectory in java. Have used [Unboundid LDAP SDK](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldapsdk/) for the same. This setup will be used for pulling data from different clients.

I've setup a Windows server with AD instance running on it. As a next step, I want to test my functionality against this AD server. However, setting up all of the "corporate level" data sounds like a big task given that I'm not terribly familiar with all of the possible configurations/group permissions setup. I did find this option which looked ideal for my scenario but the download won't complete. Please suggest what's the best way to generate "real looking" corporate data for testing AD server.
http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/LDIF%20Generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed this to setup the data.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2014/02/10/how-to-use-the-active-directory-performance-testing-tool-on-windows-server-2012.aspx

No issues faced on 2012 server.